# Do I need to repost the question if I don't get the answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I posted a question on Stack Exchange but I did not get answer even after a day. What am I supposed to do? Do I need to repost the question? Or shall I post new question by linking to the old question?

Comment: Don't repost (never repost). Wait another day, and then set a bounty on the question.

Comment: I've seen people do this, and I've always wondered ***why*** they think this might be appropriate? If you send someone an email and they don't answer right away, do you keep re-sending it until they answer it? What about a text message?

Comment: @Yannis Rizos I'm not trying to defend reposting a question, but not everyone has the reputation to set a bounty (this user hasn't).

Comment: @NiekdeKlein Well, he's very close though. But even if he was at 1 rep, reposting is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't repost...ever!
A day is not a very long time to pass. You might instead want to have a good look at your question. Is it clearly phrased? Can it be answered with the information there? Etc. Added bonus is that, should you update/improve it, it will be bumped up again.

Comment: ok i will wait. But question is fully informative . I got upvote for it. but did not get the answer I will try update it.

Comment: Surely you're not talking about [this question that you asked **5 hours ago**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629706/register-file-observer-after-mount-sd-card), right? But it's your only recent question that's received an upvote, so you must be.

Comment: ok I will wait till i get answer

Comment: If @TheEstablishment linked to the question you're talking about then 1. Be patient 2. There are surely things you can do to improve it.

Comment: I don't even guarantee responses to *text* messages within 5 hours. Surely questions you post to an online Q&A site should at least get 24-48 hours before you start to get worried or agitated. Sometimes people sleep, you know. Even experts.